# if combobox text is <none>... then

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, combobox

I have a combobox which requiers a selection other then none. Hens then I would like to know how I can add a but which cliked then checks if the combobox text is none? if so then...

thanks

update I got the following but I need to combine all the if statments so that no blanks "... "  texts are left at all..

```
        If ComboBox1.Text.Contains("<None>... ") Then
        MsgBox("Select a printing device first... ")
    Else

    If ComboBox2.Text.Contains("<None>... ") Then
        MsgBox("Select a paper format first... ")
    Else

    If ComboBox3.Text.Contains("<None>... ") Then
        MsgBox("Select a plot style first... ")
    Else
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looking to add the value from code behind, use the ddl add OR Insert method to put the value in the dropdown.

If need to put the static value than add the value using the the control property utility.

Let me know of looking for something else...

Comment: nope my example stoll pases if only one of the items is other then <none>.. by closing if youe look again you will note that not one is allowed to contain the <none>... value